# Building a c based static library for iOS

Tags: ios, static-libraries, libcurl

I need a network library for my `c` library so I can use it on both `iOS` and `android`. I've been searching around and tried to build libcurl as a static library but wasn't successful.

I built it with the following settings

```
$ export CC="clang"
$ export CFLAGS="-Wall -g -std=c11 -pipe -Os -gdwarf-2"
$ ./configure --enable-static
make install
```

It runs fine when I test the library with my test.c library. However, when I run it on my `iOS` project, I got a mismatch on `CurlchkszEQ(long, CURL_SIZEOF_LONG)`

I think the problem was that CURL_SIZEOF_LONG is set to be 8 while long in iOS is 4.

Does anyone know what went wrong with my config setting?

Comment: What kind of "mismatch" are you getting? A compiler error? A linker error? A runtime error/crash? Unexpected computation results? Nasal demons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to cross-compile libcurl for iOS but the problem here is that you use `clang` which by default produces `64-bit` `x86_64` object files.

In other words you need to work with the iOS toolchain (`xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang`), provide the right architecture flag(s)[1] (e.g `-arch armv7`) and use the right `sysroot` path.

I recommend you to refer to:

- [curl-ios-build-scripts](https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/curl-ios-build-scripts): a collection of handy scripts used to build (lib)curl for iOS 5+ and OSX 10.7+,
- or, http://seiryu.home.comcast.net/~seiryu/libcurl-ios.html which provides a ready-to-use a precompiled binary.

[1]: you may want to produce a fat library that targets ARMv7, ARMv7s and i386 (simulator) architectures.

Comment: Ah, the scripts is very useful. Thank you.